# logitech dinovo edge does not work in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, logitech

My logitech dinovo edge doesn't work at all in ubuntu 12.04.
There is no driver available. I worked in 10.04, 10.10 and 11.10. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

Salut, (english text after this one)

J'ai eu le même problème que toi. J'ai trouvé une partie de la solution ici:
http://awesomelinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/ubuntu-1004-lucid-logitech-dinovo-edge.html

La procédure est bonne mais le fichier a changé de nom. Tu dois donc effectuer la même opération sur le fichier :

**97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules**

Command:

**sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules**

Petit résumé de la procédure:

# Logitech devices

KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"

**APRÈS**

KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"

Il faut just changer le mot **hiddev** avec **hidraw**.

Et voilà, c'est fait!
Bien sûr il faut rebooter et ne pas oublier de synchroniser le clavier avec sa "clé USB" en appuyant sur les boutons connect de ces deux périphériques.

---

Hi,

I'd the same problem. I found a part of the solution here
http://awesomelinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/ubuntu-1004-lucid-logitech-dinovo-edge.html

But the file is not the right one.

You have to follow the same procedure in the file

**97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules**

Command:

**sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules**

Here is a sum up:

# Logitech devices

KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"

**AFTER**

KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"

Just change the word **hiddev** with **hidraw**.

That's it!
Don't forget to reboot the PC and synchronize both peripherals pressing the bouton connect of each device.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy `/lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d` and then modify the new file, so the rule will persists through updates.